# Assign the number of rows in a file to a variable in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

The following command would give me number of rows in a file

findstr /R /N "^" D:\Test.csv | find /C ":"

I would like to assign the number of rows to a variable and use the variable in a if condition inside a batch file.

Example: If the number of rows is 1 then rename the file.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop to capture the output of a command.

```
setlocal
for /f %%I in ('findstr /n "^" test.csv ^| find /c ":"') set "count=%%I"
if %count% equ 1 ren test.csv test.csv.1
```

Or if you don't care about maintaining `%count%` and prefer to do it all within the `for /f` loop:

```
setlocal
for /f %%I in ('findstr /n "^" test.csv ^| find /c ":"') do (
    if %%I equ 1 ren test.csv test.csv.1
)
```

Comment: Not sure what error you got, but I'm guessing you tried entering the `for /f` loop directly from the command line.  If so, replace the double `%%`s with a single `%`.  I assumed you were making a batch script, rather than running directly from the command line.  The double `%%` is for running within a .bat script.

Comment: D:\>for /f %%I in ('findstr /n "^" Test.csv ^| find /C ":"') do (if %%i==1 ren Test.csv Test.csv.1)
%%I was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Like I said, replace the double `%%`s with single if you're running directly from the command line.  `for /f %I in ('findstr /d "^" test.csv ^| find /c ":"') do if %I==1 ren test.csv test.csv.1`

Comment: Running the command with single % from command line working. But running the command in a batch(.bat) is not working. it is returning (if 2 == 1 ren Test.csv Test.csv.1)

Comment: And there is only one row in the file.

Comment: Does that row end with a line break?  If so, there are 2 lines in the file, the second of which is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here. The command worked as expected. I am new to batch file programming. Could you please suggest me a good book to start with.

Comment: *shrug* I learned by doing, making mistakes, breaking things, then trying to fix them.  I'm unfamiliar with the books available on Windows batch scripting.  I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

This is real confusing buddy...

Please comment, and reword your question...

try something like

```
@echo off
set %rows%==???

if %rows%==1 (echo You chose 1, You can replace this with any command you want)
if %rows%==2 (echo You chose 2, You can replace this with any command you want)
if %rows%==3 (echo You chose 3, You can replace this with any command you want)
```

Comment: He was asking how to capture the count of the number of lines in a file, then use that captured value in an `if` statement.